# Write down two values of $k$ for which the equation $f(x)=k$ has exactly two solutions.

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x)=5\sin(x+0.927)$

It was also written in another form as $3\sin x+4\cos x$.

I understand that for $k$ to have no solutions, the range would be $|k|>5$.
But this question confused me, because it asked for specific values rather than a range, and I assume it asks for two solutions for EACH answer of $k$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's restriction on $x$-- in $[0,2\pi]$? I ask since $f$ is periodic, so if one solution infinitely many.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Try writing your maths with this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: The restriction is -2pi to 2pi. Sorry for that confusion.